First request after Vercel deploy results in GraphQL.ExecutionError: Error trying to resolve path
After a Vercel deploy, the first request to the site results in a client side exception in which a web page does not render properly until a subsequent load. The page is rendered via SSR.

On the back end, I see this error:
Exception: GraphQL.ExecutionError
Message: Error trying to resolve path.

Nested Exception

Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.EdgeSchema
at Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.EdgeSchema.Services.Multisite.MultisiteService.ResolveSite(Item item)
at Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.EdgeSchema.GraphTypes.ItemUrlGraphType.ResolveUri(ResolveFieldContext`1 context)
at Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.EdgeSchema.GraphTypes.ItemUrlGraphType.ResolvePath(ResolveFieldContext`1 context)
at GraphQL.Resolvers.FuncFieldResolver`2.GraphQL.Resolvers.IFieldResolver.Resolve(ResolveFieldContext context)
at GraphQL.Execution.ExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteNodeAsync>d__7.MoveNext()

The front end error is:
f inner exception stack trace ---: {"response":{"data":{"search":{"total":109,"pageInfo":{"endCursor":"MTA5","hasNext":false},"results":[{"url":{"path":null}},{"url":{"path":"/path1"}},{"url":{"path":"/path2"}},{"url":{"path":"/path3"}},{"url":{"path":"/path4"}},{"url":{"path":"/path5"}},{"url":{"path":"/path6"}},{"url":{"path":"/path7"}},{"url":{"path":"/path8"}}]}},"errors":[{"message":"GraphQL.ExecutionError: Error trying to resolve path. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\r\n   at Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.EdgeSchema.Services.Multisite.MultisiteService.ResolveSite(Item item)\r\n   at Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.EdgeSchema.GraphTypes.ItemUrlGraphType.ResolveUri(ResolveFieldContext`1 context)\r\n   at Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.EdgeSchema.GraphTypes.ItemUrlGraphType.ResolvePath(ResolveFieldContext`1 context)\r\n   at GraphQL.Resolvers.FuncFieldResolver`2.GraphQL.Resolvers.IFieldResolver.Resolve(ResolveFieldContext context)\r\n   at GraphQL.Execution.ExecutionStrategy.<ExecuteNodeAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---","locations":[{"line":27,"column":11}],"path":["search","results","0","url","path"],"extensions":{"code":"NULL_REFERENCE"}}],"status":200,"headers":{}},"request":{"query":"\n  query SitemapQuery(\n    $rootItemId: String!\n    $language: String!\n    $pageSize: Int = 100\n    $hasLayout: String = \"true\"\n    $after: String\n  ) {\n    search(\n      where: {\n        AND: [\n          { name: \"_path\", value: $rootItemId, operator: CONTAINS }\n          { name: \"_language\", value: $language }\n          { name: \"_hasLayout\", value: $hasLayout }\n        ]\n      }\n      first: $pageSize\n      after: $after\n    ) {\n      total\n      pageInfo {\n        endCursor\n        hasNext\n      }\n      results {\n        url {\n          path\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n","variables":{"rootItemId":"{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}","language":"zh-CN","after":"MTAw"}}}
at /var/task/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index.js:340:31
at step (/var/task/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index.js:63:23)
at Object.next (/var/task/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index.js:44:53)
at fulfilled (/var/task/node_modules/graphql-request/dist/index.js:35:58)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
response: {
data: { search: [Object] },
errors: [ [Object] ],
status: 200,
headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] }
},
request: {
query: '\n' +
'  query SitemapQuery(\n' +
'    $rootItemId: String!\n' +
'    $language: String!\n' +
'    $pageSize: Int = 100\n' +
'    $hasLayout: String = "true"\n' +
'    $after: String\n' +
'  ) {\n' +
'    search(\n' +
'      where: {\n' +
'        AND: [\n' +
'          { name: "_path", value: $rootItemId, operator: CONTAINS }\n' +
'          { name: "_language", value: $language }\n' +
'          { name: "_hasLayout", value: $hasLayout }\n' +
'        ]\n' +
'      }\n' +
'      first: $pageSize\n' +
'      after: $after\n' +
'    ) {\n' +
'      total\n' +
'      pageInfo {\n' +
'        endCursor\n' +
'        hasNext\n' +
'      }\n' +
'      results {\n' +
'        url {\n' +
'          path\n' +
'        }\n' +
'      }\n' +
'    }\n' +
'  }\n',
variables: {
rootItemId: '{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}',
language: 'zh-CN',
pageSize: undefined,
after: 'MTAw'
}
},
page: '/sitemap.xml'
}
Node.js process exited with exit status: 1. The logs above can help with debugging the issue.

The issue appears to be related to language and an item not having a url.
Why might this be happening?

This specific error has to do with Sitemap, but the same symptom (client side error on first load and a 500 response) can also occur on any page when an unhandled error is encountered.
If you see these issues, check the logs of your head application. They should provide specific insights into what is failing.
Common culprits are:

null or undefined data / references: Cannot read properties of undefined, Cannot destructure property x of 'props.fields' as it is undefined
Issues with GraphQL queries such as: fragment with name x already exists. graphql-tag enforces all fragment names across your application to be unique

